# Android WebView evaluateJavaScript Callback is not being invoked

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, chromium

`evaluateJavascript(String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback)` method is added to WebView on Android in SDK 19.

Android documentation quotes:

> If non-null, resultCallback will be invoked with any
>   result returned from that execution.

I am using this method as shown below, but somehow my callback is not being invoked. I can see from debugging that the `evaluateJavascript()` is called, but the call back is not being invoked in Android API **19, 20 & 21**. From API 22 (LOLLIPOP_MR1) onwards, everything is working as expected.

Calling `webview.loadURL("")` before `evaluateJavascript()` makes it work on all the API levels. I want to understand why and would appreciate if somebody can shed some light / share any links about this. If I can understand why, I want to see if calling `loadURL()` could be avoided. There is another unrelated problem which makes `loadURL()` a non-preferable solution.

***Code:***

```
    private void webViewTest() {
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Log.d("TEST", "BEFORE"); // LOGGED
        // webview.loadUrl(""); // Enabling this makes it work on all Android versions
        webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return 'test'})()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                Log.d("TEST", "From JS: " + s); // NEVER LOGGED on API 19-21
            }
        });
        Log.e("TEST", "AFTER"); // LOGGED
    }


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webViewTest();
        }
    });
```

Please find an example of this problem at https://github.com/bashok001/TestApp

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html is there a reason why `loadData()` or `loadDataWithBaseURL()` can't be used instead.

Comment: As soon as I use `load...()` methods, it is breaking another functionality. So, I want to understand why calling `load...()` makes it all work in 19, 20, 21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)):

Asynchronously evaluates JavaScript in the context of the **currently displayed page**. In `ContentViewCore` `EvaluateJavascript` checks for renderview. Looks like for that particular versions of `WebView` integrated within 19,20,21 - the `RenderView` is just not created until `loadUrl` get called.

I found following [FIX](https://codereview.chromium.org/570783002/#ps20001) that could be relevant:

It's modify [WebContentsAndorid](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f08040289fb0ed72c792863d2dab73fe4d1ca943/content/browser/web_contents/web_contents_android.cc) native implementation of EvaluateJavaScript from :

```
void WebContentsAndroid::EvaluateJavaScript(JNIEnv* env,
                                             jobject obj,
                                             jstring script,
                                            jobject callback,
                                            jboolean start_renderer) {

   RenderViewHost* rvh = web_contents_->GetRenderViewHost();
   DCHECK(rvh);

   if (start_renderer && !rvh->IsRenderViewLive()) {

     if (!static_cast<WebContentsImpl*>(web_contents_)->
         CreateRenderViewForInitialEmptyDocument()) {
         ... 
     }
   }
   ...
```

to :

```
 void WebContentsAndroid::EvaluateJavaScript(JNIEnv* env,
                                                jobject obj,
                                                jstring script,
                                                jobject callback) {
   RenderViewHost* rvh = web_contents_->GetRenderViewHost();
   DCHECK(rvh);
   if (!rvh->IsRenderViewLive()) {
     if (!static_cast<WebContentsImpl*>(web_contents_)->
         CreateRenderViewForInitialEmptyDocument()) {
         ...
        }
      }
   ....
```

And in `ContentViewCore` there was following code which passing `false` as `start_renderer`:

```
public void evaluateJavaScript(String script, JavaScriptCallback callback) {
    assert mWebContents != null;
    mWebContents.evaluateJavaScript(script, callback, false);
}
```

This mean that on `WebView` built prior to mentioned fix calls to `evaluateJavaScript` does not create `RenderView` and as result `WebContext` can't handle java script execution. 
 So when you use `loadUrl` you force creation of render view and all starts working as expected.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you!