# Why JS executed in API 28 but not in 23 in webview?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have a js code that work in api 28 but not in api 23, the js code is to delete all the hyperlinks of css files,

[image]

Code:

```
  WebSettings webSettings = siteView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    siteView.setInitialScale(200);
   // JSInterface api = new JSInterface();
   // siteView.addJavascriptInterface(api, "api");
    siteView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){

                    view.evaluateJavascript("var selector = '#top1 > p > img'; document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('style'), { innerText: '*{visibility:hidden}' + selector + '{visibility:visible}' }));\n" +
                            "                document.body.style.marginLeft=\"0px\";\n" +
                            "                document.body.style.marginTop=\"0px\";\n" +
                            "                $(\"body > link:nth-child(1)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
                            "                $(\"body > link:nth-child(4)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
                            "                $(\"head > link:nth-child(18)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
                            "                document.querySelector(\"#top1 > p > img\").src=\"/ORegMx/capito.png\";", null);
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){        var selector = '#top1 > p > img'; document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('style'), { innerText: '*{visibility:hidden}' + selector + '{visibility:visible}' }));\n" +
                            "document.body.style.marginLeft=\"0px\";\n" +
                            "document.body.style.marginTop=\"0px\";\n" +
                            "$(\"body > link:nth-child(1)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
                            "$(\"body > link:nth-child(4)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
                            "$(\"head > link:nth-child(18)\").removeAttr(\"href\");\n" +
                            "document.querySelector(\"#top1 > p > img\").src=\"/ORegMx/capito.png\";\n})();");                    }

        }




    siteView.loadUrl(URL);


}
```

I think the evaluateJavascript is not working

How can i fix that ?

Appreciate any help !

Comment: I would refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325707/android-webview-evaluatejavascript-callback-is-not-being-invoked, check out the accepted answer.

Comment: @Alex Didn't understand where i put the modified code of WebContentsAndorid